# why does num block "/" don't work in the R terminal and how can I change this

Tags: r

I'm using the R terminal (Rterm). In R I often have to type "/" instead of "\" for paths. The problem is, that "/" on the num block doesn't work in the R terminal.

The regular "/" on the keyboard can only by typed with Shift (on a German keyboard).

Why can't I use num block in R terminal? Is there a way to activate num block "/" in R terminal?

Comment: Is the num block a physical keyboard? Are you asking how to reassign keys on your keyboard?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but why are you needing to type paths so much? That's usually rare, perhaps an adjustment in your coding styles would reduce the need for this, and likely also make your code more reproducible and flexible.

Comment: Despite the fact the symbols they produce look similar, the two keys generally map to different characters. The one on the keyboard is a "forward slash" and the one in the number block is "divide". (You can see that [here](http://keycode.info/)). R cannot interpret the "divide" character as a folder character. You would need to use something like `gsub()` to replace one character with the other.

Comment: Bit of a workaround, but you can create a file path by pasting a vector of folder names and using `collapse = .Platform$file.sep`

Comment: \ is an escape character in regex, so often you need to use \\ instead

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. But even if I wouldn't use it for paths. I cannot even write something like "x <- y / 5" using the num block, which doesn't seems right, because typing such things is what the num block is for.